# How do we set StrictHostKeyChecking=no for npm when running in docker container using jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, ssh, npm-install

I am trying to install `npm` modules from private repository in docker container from a **jenkins pipeline**. I have followed this blog: https://sanderknape.com/2019/06/installing-private-git-repositories-npm-install-docker/ and used the docker buildkit option.
My problem is in the ssh configuration for `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

When I run this command in docker it is successful as it adds the host to known_hosts

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=github GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git clone git@github.****
```

But while running this command, I get Host Verification failed error:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=github GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" npm install git+ssh://git@github.****
```

Also, how do we pass ssh-agent configured in jenkins pipeline to a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved at last. The problem was that git and npm were using different home directories for cloning.

Git was using root user and so had permission to check the /root/.ssh folder but somehow npm was using the directory /home/user/.ssh and was getting some permission related problems.

After doing a simple

```
RUN npm config set cache /root
```

I was able to successfully execute the below command without any problems.

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=github GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" npm install git+ssh://git@github.****
```